# script type='module' is loading successfully but not able to access

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am using one custom npm package where I am adding script to the head section.

```
  private registerScript = () => {
    if (!document.querySelectorAll('script[src="'+ this.URL+'"]').length) {
      let script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'module';
      script.src = this.URL;
      document.head.appendChild(script);

      script.onload = () => {
        console.log('script loaded successfully');
        console.log('call register event here ');
        // window.registerEvents();
        // this.registerEvents();
        try {
          // @ts-ignore
          new ActrS(this.PROJECT_ID, this.ENV, this.AGENT_ID);  // this is line 18
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('error ', error);
        }
      };
      script.onerror = () => {
        console.log('script is not loaded');
      }
  }
}
```

Above code adding the script tag successfully. It is entering into the script.onload function but giving the following error

```
error  ReferenceError: ActrS is not defined
at script.onload (index.js:18:1)
```

my code for this.URL = 'https://example.com/js/trak.js' is as following

```
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
    function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
    function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
    function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
    step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
});
};
export class ActrS {
constructor(projectId, environment = 'dev', agentId = 0) {
    this.timer = 0;
    this.DOMAIN = 'https://example.com';
    this.URL = 'https://example.com/js/trak.js';


    this.observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
        if (location.href !== this.previousUrl) {
            this.previousUrl = location.href;
            this.retryCheck = 1;
            this.registerEvents();
        }
    });
    // remove extra code
    this.checkEventAttached = (elem, event) => {
        var _a, _b;
        let result = false;
        if (elem.hasAttribute("data-act")) {
            let attachedEvent = (_b = (_a = elem.getAttribute("data-act")) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.split(",")) !== null && _b !== void 0 ? _b : [];
            if (attachedEvent.includes("c") && event == "click") {
                result = true;
            }
            else if (attachedEvent.includes("s") && event == "scroll") {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    };
    this.setProject = (parents) => {
        let returnValue = this.comonData.projectId;
        if (this.comonData.projectId !== 'ABCD') {
            for (const plugin of this.pluginIdentifier) {
                const classValue = plugin.referenceValue;
                if (parents.includes(classValue)) {
                    returnValue = plugin.name;
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    };
    this.registerEvents = () => {
        let reTryInterval = window.setInterval(() => {
            this.retryCheck += 1;
            const documentLength = document.getElementsByTagName('*').length;
            if (this.totalLength !== documentLength) {
                this.triggerTypingEvent();
                this.triggerLetEvent();
                this.totalLength = documentLength;
            }
            else {
                if (this.retryCheck >= 50) {
                    clearInterval(reTryInterval);
                    reTryInterval = undefined;
                    this.retryCheck = 1;
                }
            }
        }, 100);
    };
    this.registerScript = () => {
        if (!document.querySelectorAll('script[src="' + this.URL + '"]').length) {
            let script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = this.URL;
            document.head.appendChild(script);
            script.onload = () => {
                console.log('script loaded successfully');
                this.registerEvents();
            };
            script.onerror = () => {
                console.log('script is not loaded');
            };
        }
    };
    this.setAgentId = (agentId) => {
        this.comonData.agentId = agentId;
    };
    this.previousUrl = '';
    this.retryCheck = 1;
    this.totalLength = document.getElementsByTagName('*').length;
    this.comonData.projectId = projectId;
    if (agentId > 0) {
        this.comonData.agentId = agentId;
    }
    
    
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            console.log('content load has been called');
            this.registerEvents();
        });
    
    this.observer.observe(document, this.config);
}
}
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

Thanks.

Comment: Scripts with `type="module"` does not register global properties (on `window` object) by default. Thus in your `trak.js`, you need to assign it manually after your class definition: (e.g. `window.ActrS  = ActrS;`)

Comment: Thanks @HaoWu. You saved my day. Please give this as an answer So I will upvote this.

Comment: @HaoWu Or much simpler, just use `import()` instead of loading a `<script>`